# whenNew() with PoweMockito

Tags: junit4, powermockito

I have mocked File class constructor with PowerMockito.

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments("Filepath").thenReturn(mockFile);
```

But when my sut class create File("withSomeOtherPath"), null is returned.

I expect 'mockFile' should be returned, when called with "Filepath" argument, with other argument actual constructor should be called.

Isn't it true?

Answer (score 0):

"I  expect 'mockFile' should be returned, when called with "Filepath" argument, with other argument actual constructor should be called." ---->This is true of Spy not Mock.
Default behaviour with Spy is to call real method unless it is stubbed.

Where as with Mock the default behaviour is do Nothing when not stubbed. Hence you got `null`.

Try this

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments("Filepath").thenReturn(mockFile).thenCallRealMethos();
```

Comment: Which argument I should pass while spying File class? I want File class should return mock object with one argument and actual object with some other argument.

Comment: It gave me following error:`org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot call abstract real method on java object!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.`